# How to display welcome message dynamically in c#?

Tags: c#, json, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I am coming to a problem where I am returning a whole guid from my rest api, however I just want to get the get the WelcomeMessage to show dynamically instead of hardcoding it. can anyone help me solve this issue. thanks for the help.

I have a child name Tests above the guid

Json:

```
      {
    "42f6be79-443b-4845-8549-865af9e74988": {
        "Active": true,
        "CompletedMessage": "Placeholder",
        "CreatedBy": "",
          "Description": "Placeholder",
        "DisplayName": "Placeholder1",
        "ID": "be193200-c277-48bd-90ab-796e869f2e0b",
        "QuestionsIDs": [
            "bd341962-6c7f-459d-88ea-86aa7186840a",
            "bd341962-6c7f-459d-88ea-86aa7186840a"
        ],
         "WelcomeMessage": "Placeholder3"
    }
}
```

Code:

```
        public Text welcomeMessage; 
private async void welcomeMessage()
    {
        Dictionary<string, Questions> questionDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Questions>();

        string json = @"{https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/Tests/WelcomeMessage.json";

         questionDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Questions>>(json);

        foreach (Questions question in questionDictionary.Values)
        {
            Guid[] guids = question.QuestionsIDs; 
            string welcomeMessage = question.WelcomeMessage;

            welcomeMessageShown = GetComponent<Text>();
            welcomeMessageShown.text = welcomeMessage.ToString();

        }
```

Comment: Which programming language do you want your answer in? And most importantly what have you tried so far?

Comment: c sharp please. and thats what I have tried in the code section above.

Comment: Your json is invalid. Please post valid json

Comment: check now @HastaTamang

Comment: Can you not change your guid to something named object? Say `{ "Question" : { ...}}`

Comment: it is shown like that. it is `{ Questions { guid number { ..... }}`

Comment: I was thinking of serialising to an object. But i guess you could use regex to pull out only DisplayText.

Comment: is this without hardcoding it? I want to do it dynamically.

Comment: Your json feels weird to me. Could u also attach real json file to this question. It might help others to answer it.

Comment: I have updated my question and question topic.

Answer (score 0):

First create a class that matches your object. Lets say `Question`

```
  public partial class Question
  {
        [JsonProperty("Active")]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CompletedMessage")]
        public string CompletedMessage { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CreatedBy")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DisplayName")]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ID")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("QuestionsIDs")]
        public Guid[] QuestionsIDs { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("WelcomeMessage")]
        public string WelcomeMessage { get; set; }
 }
```

Since our json is a key value pair we need to [deserialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm) it to a Dictionary

Our dictionary definition will be

```
 Dictionary<string, Question> questionDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Question>();
```

Now using `Newtonsoft.Json` we can deserialize this to our dictionary.

```
string json = @"{
                  '42f6be79-443b-4845-8549-865af9e74988': {
                     'Active': true,
                     'CompletedMessage': 'Placeholder',
                     'CreatedBy': '',
                     'Description': 'Placeholder',
                     'DisplayName': 'Placeholder1',
                     'ID': 'be193200-c277-48bd-90ab-796e869f2e0b',
                     'QuestionsIDs': [
                          'bd341962-6c7f-459d-88ea-86aa7186840a',
                          'bd341962-6c7f-459d-88ea-86aa7186840a'
                       ],
                      'WelcomeMessage': 'Placeholder3'
                      }
                    }";

 Dictionary<string, Question> questionDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Question>>(json);

 foreach (Question question in questionDictionary.Values)
 {
       Guid[] guids = question.QuestionsIDs; // Do whatever you want with it
       string welcomeMessage = question.WelcomeMessage;
 }
```

Comment: Hey @HastaTamang thanks for the answer. But, the json is being hardcode though. Remember, I am trying retrieve data dynamically from my url which is my firebase database, and  I need to get the  `WelcomeMessage` to display the value "Placeholder3".

Comment: @johnmicheals - Can you see where in Hasta's code, you would simply access a different property instead of `QuestionIDs`?

Comment: Yes as a proof of concept it is hardcoded. string json would be whatever you get back from the firebase endpoint.

Comment: so, inside the `string json` what will be the correct url to get the value of the welcome screen?`@"https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/Tests/WelcomeMessage.json";` ?

Comment: @johnmicheals - You should know the correct URL to get the value. `string json` holds the result you get back from your firebase URL. Are you asking how to download json from Firebase?

Comment: no, but I am using this url `https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/Tests/WelcomeMessage.json` to get the value of the "WelcomeMessage"  but it is just returning as null.

Comment: `string welcomeMessage = question.WelcomeMessage;` did you not read @gravity comment

Comment: right. How about my url am I going to pass in some parameters or I can do `string json= @{"https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/Tests/WelcomeMessage.json`?

Comment: I tried by doing that well, but for some reason the `WelcomeText` key's value is not showing.

Comment: You need to make a `HttpWebRequest` to get the file from firebase then save that result of that to `string json`.

Comment: Yep that is it. What do u get in `Console.WriteLine(result);` Json is the result in my example

Comment: so, how can i combine my httpwebrequest code with your code above?

Comment: but the problem is  my url: `https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/Tests.json?orderBy="WelcomeMessage"` that  it says it WelcomeMessage cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: Of course you can. But it is nice to refactor out your request to Firebase in its separate class or function

Comment: I suggest you to ask a different question on how to download file from Firebase or search similar questions in stackoverflow.